# I was trying to make mysql server as a client of ldap server

Tags: mysql

Does opensource version of MySql support authentication using ldap & pam ? I need to use my ldap server for central authetication of all my database servers. ( Not the OS but MySql server ) OS is already configured for central auth but mysql is not working. I tried to do it via /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/authentication_pam.so but seems its not present in default installation.

Comment: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-pam-for-mysql/intro.html

Comment: Also see http://serverfault.com/questions/391942/use-ldap-for-mysql-authentication

Answer (score 0):

The official MySQL PAM Authentication plugin is a commercial option for MySQL Support customers, which is why it is not available on your installation

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/pam-authentication-plugin.html

There are a few open source plugins now available for either PAM or direct LDAP authentication, I have not used them however so cannot recommend any specific project.